# Grails 3 plugins configuration

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-3.1

New to Grails 3- starting to port.

Have tried placing config values in application.groovy and application.yml within plugin conf dir to no avail - trying to read values from within plugin service fails. Adding values to the main application's application.groovy works.

What is the secret here?  Previously I could load specific conf files via config.locations simply by naming them which was nice and simple.  I've seen some resolutions that include needing to setup env vars with paths to config files which I'd like to avoid. Then they set up file URIs for dev and classpath URIs for other envs that will be war packaged - don't really want to do any of this.

Do we no longer have the ability to place config within a plugin and have that automatically merged with the applications config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin may provide config settings in `grails-app/conf/plugin.yml`.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  So only yaml configuration is available or is there a way to have it be a groovy config file?

Comment: FYI for others - plugin.groovy is the groovy file to use within the plugin